# Finding a VBAS defnied Named Range definition

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

a valueI've inherited a large VBA project and whilst I have lots of dev expereince I have a small amount of VBA. The code reads data off a sheet in the form:

```
Intersect(Range("colName"), .Rows(intCurrentRow)).Value
```

Where colName is a named range, or so I thought. I have searched all of the project code and the excel sheets and cannot find where `colName` is defined ?

So far I have searched the code, looked in Name Manager on the sheet and have googled furiously but hit a total blank. As I now need to read in another value from the Sheet I would really prefer to use the code that is currently used with another value instead of colName to reference my new data field.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing ?

Edits:

activesheet.range("colName").address gives a value of "$L:$l"

Comment: colName in "" would mean that its a sheet level range name, it could be a dynamic range, offset(a1,0,0,counta(a:a),1) for example for an expanding range, that may not appear in the CTRL G list of names, check in the Define Names box see if its there.

Comment: It's not listed on Define Names ...

Comment: in the immediate pane, try activesheet.range("colName").address  does the code open another sheet, or define the range?

Comment: Is there an `On Error ...` statement above the intersect? Perhaps it never worked properly? What happens when you put a breakpoint on that line? What is the value/address of `Range("colName")` when it arrives there? Stepping into and past that line, is anything processed? You have not provided enough code/data/behavior examples to determine anything.

Comment: @Jeeped I appreciate that. If I break on that line and hover over Value I get no value given by the IDE - adding a Watch gives an invalid property error, however, the value is part of a set of parameters passed to another function - breaking in the function and reading the value passed in shows it si reading a value from the sheet. I just cannot understand where colName is defined.

Comment: probably a hidden name: try unhiding it to see

Comment: @Nathan_Sav range("colName").address gives a value of "$L:$l"

Comment: I second what @CharlesWilliams suggested. Try ActiveWorkbook.Names("colName").Visible=True.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams thank you for that - I really thought that was it - there is a function to HideNames that I commented out - unfortunately no further ranges have appeared.

Comment: @DougGlancy - ok we're getting somehwere - typing that in the immediate window caused the named range to appear, so I guess I can add another range with the HideRange function enabled and it will be defined then be hidden with the rest.

Comment: OK that worked fine - if someone would like to add it as the answer I'll very happily accept it as being correct. Many thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably a hidden name.As Doug Glancy said, you can unhide it using VBA

```
Activeworkbook.Names("colName").Visible=True
```

If you are working with defined names you may find it useful to get My & Jan Karel Pieterse's Name Manager addin which (amongst many other things) handles hidden names. download from
http://www.decisionmodels.com/downloads.htm

Answer (score 2):

It could be a hidden Name. Try:
`ActiveWorkbook.Names("colName").Visible=True`